# Scala fatal warnings but excluding deprecations flag not work

Tags: scala, sbt, scalac, scala-compiler

According to https://alexn.org/blog/2020/05/26/scala-fatal-warnings.html

`"-Wconf:cat=deprecation:ws,any:e"`

Will turn warnings into errors, except for deprecations.  But it gives this:

```
[error] bad option: '-Wconf:cat=deprecation:ws,any:e'
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

where

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.12"
```

Comment: `Wconf` was added on `2.13.4`.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez it was actually added in Scala 2.13.2 :) Here is the PR: https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/8373 . This link is part of the attached article.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thanks, we are stuck on 2.12 thanks to Spark :(. Will have to wait for Spark to catch up.

Comment: @samthebest you could take a look to the [**silencer**](https://github.com/ghik/silencer) plugin.